# Ho to get last item in mysql using max()

Tags: mysql

I want to get the last item as result using `max()`, but i'm just getting the first item even if im using `max()`
[image]

**Here's the SQL code:**

```
SELECT r.correct, r.items, r.percentage,MAX(r.date_taken) as date_taken,
       u.username,u.FN, u.user_course_type,
       IFNULL(u.user_major_type,'N/A') as user_major_type,u.level_name,
       u.section_name
FROM bcc_fs_exam_result r
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT u.id_user, u.username, CONCAT(u.lastname,', ',u.firstname) as FN,
 c.user_course_type, m.user_major_type, l.level_name, s.section_name
 FROM bcc_fs_user u 
 LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_user_course c on c.id_user_course = u.id_user_course
 LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_user_major m on m.id_user_major = u.id_user_major
 LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_group_level l ON l.id_level = u.id_level
 LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_group_section s ON s.id_section = u.id_section
) u ON r.id_user = u.id_user WHERE r.id_exam = 5 GROUP BY r.id_user
```

TIA

Comment: the date changes but the (correct,items & percentage) did not change at all what am i missing

Comment: well basically it is connected they're in same table after all, so it should be coinciding with the other fields whenever i filter using the date the fields (correct,items and percentage) stays the same

Answer (score 0):

What I take from your question is that you want to get the "correct", "items", "percentage" ect. columns of the row in `bcc_fs_exam_result` which has the last or first date.

If that's correct then you can filter `bcc_fs_exam_result` by first finding what is the min or max date by for each `id_user` then join that back on the exam results table.

```
SELECT 
    r.correct,
    r.items, 
    r.percentage, 
    r.date_taken,
    u.username, 
    u.FN, 
    u.user_course_type, 
    IFNULL(u.user_major_type,'N/A') as user_major_type, 
    u.level_name, 
    u.section_name 
FROM bcc_fs_exam_result r   
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT u.id_user, 
        u.username, 
        CONCAT(u.lastname,', ',u.firstname) as FN, 
        c.user_course_type, 
        m.user_major_type, 
        l.level_name, 
        s.section_name 
    FROM bcc_fs_user u 
        LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_user_course c on c.id_user_course = u.id_user_course 
        LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_user_major m on m.id_user_major = u.id_user_major 
        LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_group_level l ON l.id_level = u.id_level 
        LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_group_section s ON s.id_section = u.id_section

) u ON r.id_user = u.id_user 

INNER JOIN (    
    SELECT 
        id_user, max(r.date_taken) as last_date_taken
    FROM bcc_fs_exam_result
    GROUP BY id_user
) as lastdate ON  lastDate.id_user = r.id_user and r.date_taken = lastdate.last_date_taken
```

which could be more simply written as :

```
SELECT 
    r.correct,
    r.items, 
    r.percentage, 
    r.date_taken,
    u.username, 
    CONCAT(u.lastname,', ',u.firstname) as FN, 
    c.user_course_type, 
    IFNULL(m.user_major_type,'N/A') as user_major_type, 
    l.level_name,
    s.section_name 
FROM bcc_fs_exam_result r   
INNER JOIN (    
    SELECT 
        id_user, max(r.date_taken) as last_date_taken
    FROM bcc_fs_exam_result
    GROUP BY id_user
) as lastdate ON  lastDate.id_user = r.id_user and r.date_taken = lastdate.last_date_taken

INNER JOIN bcc_fs_user u on r.id_user = u.id_user
LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_user_course c on c.id_user_course = u.id_user_course 
LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_user_major m on m.id_user_major = u.id_user_major 
LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_group_level l ON l.id_level = u.id_level 
LEFT JOIN bcc_fs_group_section s ON s.id_section = u.id_section
```

You have assumed that `id_user` + `date_taken` is a surrogate key of `bcc_fs_exam_result` which you should probably enforce with a constraint if at all possible. Otherwise it looks from your sample data that the order of the unique id column `id_result` follows the `date_taken`so you might be better to use `Max(id_result)` rather than `Max(date_taken)`. That would avoid returning duplicate rows for one `id_user` where two rows of `bcc_fs_exam_result` have the same `taken_date` and `id_user.